# How did Hindu-Arabic Numerals get their shapes?

Tags: notation, numbers

I’ve noticed a recurring post on social media that presents an image suggesting the shapes of Hindu-Arabic numerals are connected to the angles within their design:
[image: hindu-arabic shapes from angles?]

This claim seems dubious to me.

I am seeking a definitive and reliable reference regarding the evolution of the Hindu-Arabic numerals. Specifically, my question is: How did the ten Hindu-Arabic numerals (0-9) come to have their current forms?

If anyone could point me towards scholarly articles, historical texts, or authoritative studies on this subject, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: This is a fake story!

Comment: this has been disproved many times: https://www.jefflewis.net/blog/2009/10/origin_of_arabic_numerals_was_1.html